# Typescript in package.json dependency

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I just boostrapped a React project with typescript with the following command:

`npx create-react-app frontend --template typescript`

[image]

I am surprised to find `tyepscript` but also @testing and @types libraries into my dependencies and not my devDependencies. Won't these libraries being in dependencies increase the production bundle?

EDIT: synthetic answer > as MjZac pointed out in the comments, devDependencies and dependencies are mainly semantics when we are talking about a static web app like React. Also, putting things into dependencies will not impact webpack bundling behavior.

See: [https://jsramblings.com/do-dependencies-devdependencies-matter-when-using-webpack/#:~:text=Do%20%22dependencies%22%20and%20%22devDependencies%22%20matter%20when%20using%20Webpack%3F,-12%20Mar%202020&text=When%20using%20Webpack%20to%20bundle,statements%2C%20starting%20with%20the%20entryPoint%20.](https://jsramblings.com/do-dependencies-devdependencies-matter-when-using-webpack/#:%7E:text=Do%20%22dependencies%22%20and%20%22devDependencies%22%20matter%20when%20using%20Webpack%3F,-12%20Mar%202020&text=When%20using%20Webpack%20to%20bundle,statements%2C%20starting%20with%20the%20entryPoint%20.).

Comment: This is intentionally made so. For context, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4342

Comment: really interesting

Comment: this is really bad.  I'm getting all kinds of dependency conflicts with these types when trying to include other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they won't be automagically bundled in if they're in `dependencies`. Only the code you use will be bundled in.

(Nevertheless, I tend to like to have build-time dependencies in `devDependencies`.)